# Better bound for $f$ with Maximum Modulus Principle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic in $D = \{z : |z| < 1\}$ and suppose that $|f(z)| \le M$ for all $z$ in $D$. If $|f(z_k)| = 0$ for $1 \le k \le n$, show that
$$
|f(z)| \le M \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{|z-z_k|}{|1-\bar{z_k}z|}
$$
for $|z| < 1$.

My attempt: since $f/\varphi$ has removable singularities at $z_k$, we can redefine the function $\frac{f}{\varphi}$, where $$\varphi(z) = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{z-z_k}{1-\bar{z_k}z},$$ and consider $g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{\varphi(z)}$, which is analytic in $D$. If I can show that $|g(z)| \le M$, then I'm done. Seeking a contradiction, suppose $g(w) > M$ for some $w \in D$. For $|w| < r < 1$, consider $$\max_{|z| \le r} |g(z)| = \max_{|z|=r} |g(z)|.$$
I'm stuck at this step. I know $|f|$ is bounded, but I can't use the bounds for $f$ and $\varphi$ separately because $\varphi$ may be 0.

Am I on the right track? How can I make the arguments go smoothly? It seems like I'm close, but not there yet.

Thank you.

Comment: Are the $z_k \in D$?

Comment: You don't want absolute values in the definition of $\varphi.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $z_k  \in D$ for $k=1, \ldots, n$ and $f(z_k) = 0$. Since $|f(z)| \leq M$ then 
\begin{align}
g_1(z):=\frac{1}{M}f(z) 
\end{align}
is a mapping from $D\rightarrow D$ which is analytic. Next, define the following maps
\begin{align}
\varphi_k(z) = \frac{z-z_k}{1-\bar z_k z}
\end{align}
which is an automorphism of the disk back to itself.

Observe $g_1\circ \varphi_1^{-1}:D\rightarrow D$  and $g_1\circ \varphi_1^{-1}(0)= g(z_1) = 0$. Then by Schwarz's lemma we have that
\begin{align}
|g_1(z)| \leq |\varphi_1(z)| = \left|\frac{z-z_1}{1-\bar z_1 z} \right|.
\end{align}

Next, define the function
\begin{align}
g_2(z) = g_1(z)/\varphi_1(z)
\end{align}
which is analytic because $g_1(z_1)= 0$, i.e. $g_2(z)$ as a removable singularity at $z_1$. Moreover, observe $g_2:D\rightarrow D$ since
\begin{align}
|g_2(z)| = |g_1(z)|/|\varphi_1(z)| \leq 1 
\end{align} 
by the above estimate. Next, observe $g_2\circ \varphi_2^{-1}:D\rightarrow D$ and $g_2\circ \varphi_2^{-1}(0)=g_2(z_2) =0$. Then again by Schwarz's lemma, we have that
\begin{align}
|g_2(z)| \leq |\varphi_2(z)| = \left|\frac{z-z_2}{1-\bar z_2 z} \right| \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ |g(z)| \leq \left| \frac{z-z_1}{1-\bar z_1 z}\right|\left| \frac{z-z_2}{1-\bar z_2 z}\right|.
\end{align}

Inductively, we see that
\begin{align}
|g(z)| \leq \prod^n_{k=1} \left| \frac{z-z_k}{1-\bar z_k z}\right| \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ |f(z)|  \leq M\prod^n_{k=1} \left| \frac{z-z_k}{1-\bar z_k z}\right|. 
\end{align}

Comment: I really like your proof. Can you explain why we have $|g_1(z)| \le |\varphi_1(z)|$ by the Schwarz's Lemma? I think we have $|g_1 \circ \varphi_1^{-1} | \le |z|$. Then what's next? Thank you.

Comment: Observe you have $|g_1\circ \varphi_i^{-1}(z)| \leq |z|$. Then if we set $y = \varphi^{-1}_1(z)$ we will get that $|g_1(y) | \leq |z| = |\varphi_1(y)|$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $a\in D,$ the function $\psi (z) = (z-a)/(1-\bar a z)$ satisfies

$$ \inf_{|z|= r} |\psi (z)| \to 1\,\text { as } r\to 1^-.$$

Hence the same holds for any finite product of such functions, such as your

$$\varphi(z) = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{z-z_k}{1-\bar{z_k}z}.$$

Therefore, by the maximum modulus theorem,

$$ \max_{|z|\le r} \left| \frac{f(z)}{\varphi (z)}\right | \le \frac{M}{\inf_{|z|= r} |\varphi (z)|}.$$

Letting $r\to 1^-$ shows that $|f/\varphi| \le M$ in $D.$ Hence $|f|\le M|\varphi|$ in $D$ as desired.

Comment: Will the fact that $\varphi$ can be 0 inside $D$ affect the arguments? It looks like $\max_{|z| \le r} | f(z) / \varphi(z) |$ can be affected. This is what makes me not using the arguments? Could you please explain more to me? Thank you.

Comment: As soon as $r> \max(|z_1|,\dots ,|z_n|)$ everything is fine.